# Adding Motion Banner into a Website using HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, banner, motion

I'm currently working on a full-stack website, and I'm designing the front-end part using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

I want to add a motion banner on the main page of my website (The motion banner will present the most read articles), as shown in the following prototype:

[MainPage of MyWebsite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpmuQ.png)

How can I do that using JavaScript?
Do I have to make the little squares buttons, then when the user presses on them the banners get changed? How can I make the banners get changed automatically, after every few seconds?

Could anyone send me some links which I can follow to create this motion banner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to stack overflow!

There are many ways to make a carousel, but a viable option could to be use someone else's library which they've already written. After a quick Google for 'js carousel', I found these:

- [w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)
- [slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)
- [glide](https://glidejs.com)
- [owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)
- [flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I click on this [link](https://mobilemonkey.com/case-studies/mobilemonkey) I will see that after a couple of seconds a narrow strip/bar will appear at the bottom of the page. I have a website built with `Nunjucks` template (`html`, `javascript`, etc) that I would like to place a simple unobtrusive banner (narrow strip) on its homepage, to appear after a few second, where I can provide a little text or link or invitation to a survey. Is the answer to this post how I should do it, or is what I am looking for a totally different thing?

Comment: @Muhy you're after something very different :) If you take a look at some of the links in my post you'll see what a carousel is ;) There are probably libraries out there for 'sticky bottom banner' type things that you're after, but its also something you could definitely write yourself without too much trouble